# Spawning sprites with for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, html5-canvas

I'm having trouble spawning multiples of the same sprite in random locations of the canvas. The var = obstacle is the one I'm talking about. We are trying to do this with a for loop. Please help?

Jsbin link : http://jsbin.com/warurijuji/2/edit

code thats not working:

```
//Uploading obstacle image
var obstacle = new Image();
obstacle.src = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dE5my5trgGU/TyQ4ULWlXhI/AAAAAAAABTE/lD1Al2Vql1c/s320/cartoon+pineapple+clipart.png";

//for loop for spawning it
function drawObstacle() {

  for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {

          var x1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 299);
          var y2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 299);

          context.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";

          if (x1 > 40 && y2 > 40) {

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x1, y2, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
          } else--i;
        }
  }
```

Comment: `obstacle` isn't used in the function, so what does "spawning" mean?

Comment: Good point.Fixed, but its still not working: http://jsbin.com/legovobeya/2/edit

Comment: What does `object` even have to do with that loop?  Since it's just drawing circles, there's no reason that I can see to have an image.

Comment: Your code from link does not match what you have posted here, please update post. The link fails because you have no key handlers..